# How to get OAuth token when we use GraphAPI?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using the “PublicClientApplication.class” from the MSAL library and the “acquireToken(UserNamePasswordParameters)” method for generating the OAuth token till date. Now we are planning to migrate from Exchange EWS to GraphAPI. In this case, if I have the same java code for getting the OAuth token and just change the scope parameter in UserNamePasswordParameters to refer to the GraphAPI scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default as scope, will that get me Oauth token for Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0):

To acquire a token for the app, you'll use AcquireTokenForClient or its equivalent, depending on the platform.
[image]

Please refer docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-acquire-token?tabs=java#acquiretokenforclient-api